# Terminate laravel app not in route handler and send response

Tags: php, laravel, exception, response

I need to terminate laravel app in class method, not in route handler.
I use custom Exception and method render() it work fine but I think it is not best way.

Second way I use:

```
redirect()->back()->with(...)->send();
die();
```

but by this way dont work with() method and Session flush, work only redirect...
when I dump session it empty...
What the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you to use `die()` function, you stop the execution and Laravel does not write in session the data added during the execution, you will need use `session()->save()` to force write in session, but don't is the better way.

Maybe you can just put a `return` in your code:
`return redirect()->back()->with(...)->send();`

Comment: Thanks, Now I understand problem with non saving session... Of course I'd like to use `return`, but this function not in route controller. This function like Laravel validate function, the function is executed not directly in the controller method, thats why i can not use `return`. It function like Laravel validate, and Laralev use ValidateExcetion for this issue. I think it is the best way, and you?

Comment: If you are using this code in `render()` method in a custom exception handler the return statement is correct, because render method expect that one `\Illuminate\Http\Response` will be returned and `redirect()` helper return a response.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, Now I understand that, custom exception and method render the best way, because Laravel do the same way. I wrote in question, that way( with custom exception ) work perfect, of course with h `return` and without send(). But I was searching another way. Ok, Thank you Eder Soares.